# Using querySelectorAll to select all href that matches document.URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to add a class when an href matches the document's URL using:

```
<script>
    currentLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+document.URL+'"]')
    currentLinks.forE‌​ach(function(link) {
        link.className += ' current-link'
    });
</script>
```

However, I'm stuck on the first line as it returns an empty nodelist.

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+document.URL+'"]')
```

HTML

```
<li role="presentation" class="current nav-level-5 nav-entry-1 list-position-1  links-open"><a id="perc-navigation-menuitem-nav-level-5-nav-entry-1-list-position-1-113428783" href="/-training-test/menu-test/sub-menu-1/another-level-1/" role="menuitem">Another Level 1</a></li>
```

Also, what is the use of the next selectors (+) in `+document.URL+`? Why not just use `a[href="document.URL"]` as it returns the full path?

[Link](https://dhdev.csudh.edu/-training-test/menu-test/sub-menu-1/another-level-1/)

Comment: did you put this script at the end of the document?

Comment: yes, before body close

Comment: How do links in the source actually look like?

Comment: add also the HTML, cause maybe you don't have an `a` element with the href attribute equals to all the URL returned by `document.URL`.
For your second question, that's a concat of a string and a variable which holds a string

Comment: `+` isn’t part of the selector. It’s the string concatenation operator. `'a[href="'document.URL'"]'` is a SyntaxError.

Comment: would only work if you have full absolute href's. If using relative ones you will have to loop over all `a`

Comment: Given a link `const link = document.querySelector("a[href]")`, look at its actual `href` attribute: `console.log(link.getAttribute("href"));`. Does the output match your expectation and could it ever be exactly equal to `document.URL`? That is, do all links that you expect to potentially match contain the _full URL_ in their attributes?

Comment: Taking into account your last edit, `location.pathname` (instead of `document.URL`) may be what you're looking for. You may have to cut the trailing `/` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `href` attribute in your HTML is `/-training-test/menu-test/sub-menu-1/another-level-1/`. But `document.URL` is a fully-qualified URL, something like `http://www.yourdomain/com/-training-test/menu-test/sub-menu-1/another-level-1/`, so the `href` doesn't match this exactly.

Instead of `document.URL`, try using `location.pathname`, which is just the pathname part of the URL.